# Multiprocessing in enumerate loop

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a script that downloads images from urls, but I would like to parallelise it otherwise it will take hours. With this code:

```
import requests
from math import floor, log10
import urllib 
import time
import multiprocessing

with open('images.csv', 'r') as f:
    images = f.readlines()

num_position = floor(log10(len(images)) + 1)

a = time.time()

for i, image in enumerate(images[1:10]):
    if (i+1) % 1000 == 0:
        print('Downloading {} image'.format(i+1) )
#   a = time.time()
    with open(str(i).zfill(num_position)+'a.jpg', 'wb') as file:
        try:
            writing = file.write(requests.get(image.split(',')[2]).content)
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=writing, args=(image,))  
            p.start()
            p.join()    
        except:
            print('Skipping an image!')
            pass
b = time.time()
print('multiple process -- {}'.format(b-a))
```

I get an error :

```
    Process Process-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

1. Why am I getting an error but the task is still completed and the code doesn't break? (and by that I mean the piece in try: )
2. What would be the easiest way to include some kind of paralleling here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because AFAIK this line

```
writing = file.write(requests.get(image.split(',')[2]).content)
```

has the output of integer type. `write` returns the number of written characters which is equal to the length of the string-representation of your image. Now you assign that to the variable `writing` -> `writing` becomes a number.

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=writing, args=(image,))
```

calls `writing` as target function, which raises the error since your are not calling a function but integer-type `writing` (not callable). The code works since your workers do not have anything to do and close immediatly and the file is already written.

To get things working, your would have to define a function that takes your image as argument and maybe the file name. This function you later call in the setup of your workers. Something like that:

```
def write_file(image, filename):
    filestream = open(filename, mode="w")
    filestream.write(requests.get(image.split(',')[2]).content)
    filestream.close()
```

And in your application

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=write_file, args=(image, filename,))
```

However, that is just the writing part. If you want to do the downloads in separate task too then you have to put the code for that into your separate function.

```
def download_write(urls):
    for url in iter(urls.get, 'STOP'):
        #download code here#
        filestream = open(filename, mode="w")
        filestream.write(requests.get(image.split(',')[2]).content)
        filestream.close()
```

And your main application:

```
list_urls = [] # your list of urls to download
urls = Queue()
for element in list_urls:
    urls.put(element)
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=download_write, args=(urls,))
urls.put("STOP") #signals end of tasks for your workers
p.start() #start worker
p.join() #wait for worker to finish
```